gitignore files with a particular hash but git add if hash changes
I don't want to commit or stage files that matches particular hash value but if I edit those files later it should be staged when I do git add.
Any suggestions? Basically there are files that are periodically generated and the content is copied from the template, so I don't want to stage these files unless I modify the contents of those files (without modifications in the file name or path).

you could probably write a pre-commit hook to make sure that there is no file that matches that particular hash value.
